# Static contract unproven, because reference is passed to another method (that only reads)

Tags: c#, debugging, static-analysis, code-contracts

Any one else had trouble with contracts. I have the following:

```
public void doSomeThing(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Requires(stack != null);

    stack.Push("$");
    Contract.Assert(stack.Count > 0); //redundant check
    _Look(stack);
    Contract.Assert(stack.Count > 0); //this contract fails static analysis, because analyser does not know that _Look does not write to stack.
    stack.Pop();
}

private void _Look(Stack stack)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

The second assert is unproven, because the call to _Look may ( but does not ) change the content of the stack. Is there a way to say that _Look does not change stack? Or is there some other way to get this to work?

Note these contracts pass dynamically, it is just that the second one can not be proved statically.

Comment: I would guess this isn't the way you are actually using the asserts.  Can you provide a more "real" example?  I'm not sure why you would be doing the above.

Comment: it is pretty close to an original bit of code, I simplified the name of the _Look method and the string put on the stack.

Comment: If I don't have the second assert then pop in unproven as it requires Count > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer based on idea from reading Craig Wilson's answer.

```
public void doSomeThing(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Requires(stack != null);

    stack.Push("$");
    Contract.Assert(stack.Count > 0); //redundant check
    _Look(stack);
    Contract.Assert(stack.Count > 0); //this contract fails static analysis, because analyser does not know that _Look does not write to stack.
    stack.Pop();
}

private void _Look(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Ensures(stack.Count == Contract.OldValue(stack.Count));
}
```

Comment: looking at this again, it makes no sense that _Look does not return something.

Answer (score 2):

So, it appears as though you are using Contracts to verify that your _Look method works correctly.  I believe the correct way of doing this is to move the pre and post verifications into the _Look method.  To being with, your first assert is unncessary unless you don't trust the Stack, which is out of your control.  In light of this, I'd do the following:

```
public void doSomeThing(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Requires(stack != null);

    stack.Push("$");
    _Look(stack);
    stack.Pop();
}

private void _Look(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Requires(stack != null);
    Contract.Requires(stack.Count > 0);

    //do something here

    Contract.Assert(stack.Count > 0);     
}
```

Contracts are meant for pre and post verification, not assertions in the middle of code.

Comment: Ha you have given me an idia. Contract.Ensures(stack.Count == Contract.OldValue(stack.Count)); in _Look

Comment: I would had thought that  Contract.Ensures(stack.Equals(Contract.OldValue(stack))); would work but it appears not to.

Comment: Requires and Ensures are pre and post conditions, but Contract.Assert is an in-line Check.

Comment: I just noted that the Assert above should be an Ensure (and moved to the top).

Answer (score 0):

Since Code Contracts doesn't know anything about what the `_Look` method does, it can't know that the `Count` will remain the same. You need to explicitly tell it this:

```
private void _Look(Stack stack)
{
    Contract.Ensures(stack.Count == Contract.OldValue(stack.Count));

    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Correct but (probably accidental) copy of a previous comment.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what is going on here. The second assert should pass. Unless you are not popping anything. It should stay there. Only thing here is push and pop and assert.

Comment: What does _Look do? (stack is a reference type)

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. Maybe remove it? I have never seen _Look before in c# If you remove that everything should be ok.

Comment: It is a method call, the method is private so I prefixed it with a _

Comment: Make sure there is no ".pop()" anywhere in the code before the second assert. Do a peek. Somewhere it is removing it somehow.

Comment: no it is not, it passes dynamically. This is about proving statically. I have analysed _Look and proved to my self. But even if _Look is an empty method then the static analyser that does and must work locally will declare that it can not prove it. Remember failure to prove is not proof of failure.

Comment: How is an answer saying "I don't know" useful?